# lubuntu 19.10 / myria MY8312SV / discover app / can not obtain lock

Tags: lubuntu, lock, discover-software-center

I can not install nor upgrade anything

'can not get lock var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. it is held by the process 2469 ...'

could you suggest what to do to ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo kill -HUP 2469` to end process (probably background upgrade), or wait for the process to finish.